# Ploting melted variable using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a plot with 6 facets.

I am using a melted [dataset](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22681355/g.Rdata).

When using :

```
ggplot(g,aes(x = x, y = value, colour = variable, linetype = variable,size = variable)) + 
    geom_line() + facet_wrap(.~condition)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in layout_base(data, vars, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting
```

I don't understand what this means given that I have the variable used for faceting in the variable "condition"

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22681355/o.Rdata) is the original data from which the melted variable was created.

This is the code I'm using to produce the plot:

```
ggplot(g,aes(x = x, y = as.numeric(value), colour = varible, linetype = variable,size = variable)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,10,1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,1, 0.1))+
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("red3","red3","red3","red3", "red3","red3","red3", "red3","red3",   
    "blue3","blue3","blue3","blue3","blue3","blue3","blue3","blue3","blue3")) + 
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)) + 
    scale_size_manual(values = c(0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4)) + 
    xlab("\nTime-steps") + 
    ylab("Proportion correct\n") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=5),
          axis.title=element_text(size=5),
          axis.line = element_line(size=0.25),
          axis.ticks=element_line(size=0.25),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          legend.position="none" ,
          legend.direction="vertical", 
          legend.title=element_blank(),
          legend.text=element_text(size=6), 
          legend.background=element_blank(), 
          legend.key=element_blank())+facet_wrap(~condition)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two main problems - y is coded as a factor and should be numeric, and more importantly there is a tiny typo in your facet_wrap term, which should be without `.`:

```
p <- ggplot(g,aes(x = as.numeric(x), y = as.numeric(value), group = variable)) 
p <- p + geom_line()
p <- p + facet_wrap(~condition)
p
```

This gives me

[image]

EDIT: I noted that variable has a size coding embedded. This works nicely to include it in the graphs:

```
g$size<-substring(g$variable,1,5)
```

Then add `colour = size` in the aesthetics and you obtain:

[image]

Comment: somehow it still doesn't work for me. this is what I get now: Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: Did you execute exactly the code I posted? Even if I use your code with color and linetypes it works but not properly as R runs out of colors and linetypes as there are so many different variables. `ggplot(g,aes(x = x, y =as.numeric(value), group=variable, colour = variable, linetype = variable,size = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + facet_wrap(~condition)`
I am asking because we are not doing anything with the scales. Note that x is also coded as a factor and perhaps should also be numeric?

Comment: Hi I tried the exact code you posted but I still get the error. also please the full code that I use for the plot in my update

Comment: As I thought - you are changing scales and implicitly assuming that x is numeric but it is coded as a factor. So include `x=as.numeric(x)`. Then your code has a typo in "varible" and after that fails because of the large number of variables (see my EDIT for one solution to this).

Comment: As noted you should drop `linetype = variable,size = variable` as your variable has too many levels.