# Facet_wrap on data.frame that looks like melted data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a datset (`A.plot`) that due to the data is more or less looks like it have been melted using melt. Column 1 is samples called `Prov` (9 sample names replicated 10 times each), Column 2 is step, called `Steg`, (1:10 replicated 10 times), and Column 3:30 is different metals. The samples and steps are non unique by themselves but if concatenated together one gets the true unique sample name. I have created a vector that contains all the metal names called `Element`.

```
str(A.plot)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   99 obs. of  31 variables:
 $ Prov: chr  "A-HCl" "A-HCl" "A-HCl" "A-HCl" ...
 $ Steg: num  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ Li  : num  1.51 4.22 4.76 5.3 8.89 ...
 $ Be  : num  0.204 0.559 0.802 0.841 0.295 ...
 $ Na  : num  6097217 5991299 5819005 5921011 6042524 ...
 $ Mg  : num  405 22524 333229 553882 879715 ...
 $ Al  : num  446 459 525 508 503 ...
 $ K   : num  549282 505039 500718 515440 535693 ...
```

By only plotting one metal using the following code:

```
A.test.plot <- A.plot[ , c( 1:2, 12) ] 
colnames(A.test.plot) <- c("Prov", "Steg", "value")

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
ggplot(A.test.plot, aes(x=Steg, y=value, colour=Prov, group=Prov)) +
  geom_line()
```

I can get the plot for how I want each metal to be displayed:

[image: Correct plot of one metal]

The problem is, I want all the metals in one `facet_wrap`. I have previously used gather() to `facet_wrap` several metals but then each metal(each panel) have only had one set of data/values. Now that I have several (9) sets of values to be fed into each panel it seems that I fed `gather()` the wrong way.

I have tried:

```
A.test.plot1 <- A.plot 
colnames(A.test.plot1) <- c("Prov", "Steg", Element)

gather(A.test.plot1, key = Element, value, -"Steg", -"Prov")

ggplot(gather(A.test.plot1, key=Element, value="value", -"Steg", -"Prov"), aes(x=Steg, y=Element, colour=Prov, group=Prov) ) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Element, scales = 'free')
```

But it seems that it gathers "to much":

[image: Failed facet_wrap]

I have also tried several combinations of removing Steg/Element/Prov from both the gather function and the ggplot but that only got me further from the goal.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161692/ploting-melted-variable-using-facet-wrap), but the data set is gone from the link and I am not skilled enough to reproduce the solution for my data. I have also looked at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223012/plot-multiple-days-data-of-multiple-homes-in-facet-form-of-ggplot) but I don't think that package `lubridate` is applicable here.

Edit: Sample data upon request: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_d5xWdIdsH2nl-E_YggTSTON3swP0tSehurLQqtFrt8/edit?usp=sharing
Note that it is huge due to the many decimals.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(A.test.plot1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(A.test.plot1, 20))`.

Comment: Sure, I have added sample data to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
gather(A.test.plot1, key=Element, value="value", -"Steg", -"Prov") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Steg, y=as.numeric(value), colour=Prov, group=Prov) ) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Element, scales = 'free')
```

[image]

The issue was the specification `y=Element` in the call to `aes()`.

Comment: Thank you! I am glad that I was not to far from the solution so at least I am getting better :-)